# Unity3d - Rotate Towards Space.World

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, position

I want you to turn the cube to the targeted angle. But as you will turn every angle, the concept of "Space.World" is confused. How can I integrate "Space.World" into the "RotateToward" function.

I need to use "localPosition & eulerAngles" in code ?

etc:

```
targetRotate = new Vector3(0,180,0);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (getRotate (), Quaternion.Euler (targetRotate), rotateTime * Time.deltaTime);
```

[Code in Gist](https://gist.github.com/sefatunckanat/2d3a6a90205acb2b0e1041774c28653f#file-moverotatetask-cs-L149)

Comment: You want your cube to rotate towards an angle without moving ? Or do you want it to rotate around?

Comment: e.g W key press +90 again +90 turn the x axis. Like a mission, that ax will turn with animation. like a lerp, rotate towards. Like a dice but turn value every time 90 on x,y,z axis :/